# Feeds - Is there a way to pick an choose which feed items get created as a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-feeds

I'm grabbing a rss xml and using xpath parser etc to map the fields and create nodes. I've also used Feeds Tamper, Feeds Tamper php to take some feed items, perform logic and alter a fields content.

I'd like to know if there is a way to 'pre process' the feed items before nodes are created, perform logic on some source fields to work out i want to create a node from it?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Feeds API hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/7), one of those in a custom module should let you alter the feed source beforehand - try [hook_feeeds_after_parse](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_parse/7) to alter `$result`